# How to save control state locally on user's machive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I have an aspx page (ASP.NET page) that I need to persist the state of some of its controls to the user's machine. But I don't need to persist all the controls on the page, only some of them, for example:
Let's say I have a DropDownList, a ListBox and a button, btnAdd. When the user selects a value in the ddl and clicks the button, the value is added to the LB.
In addtion, I have an additional button to, btnSave, to save the query, so that the user can have sort of like 'templates' for this page.
This page really is a simple report page, so I have several such ddls and lbs.

How can I persist the controls on the user's machine and then load them in the future?

thanks,
ashilon

Comment: use `Viewstate` for particular page or use html5 `localStorage()` to get value in all the pages

Comment: How do I serialize the viewstate of an asp.net listbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for HTML5 enabled browsers by -

```
window.localStorage.setItem
```

and retrive using `localStorage.getItem`

If you want to use it for non HTML5 complient browsers then you can use **cookies**.

Comment: Interesting approach, but how do I let the user interact with local storage/cookies? With local files, the user can choose from several previously saved files.

Comment: Strategy you need to develope as  per your requirement. And values should not be huge. Key value pairs or JSON will work. And always update the same key in cookie or local storage if it is already exists.. And it is your code which will interact with storage/cookies not user.